# Having delegate problems for my Navigation controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

so i have a navigation controller, and in it i have a view and a scrollview embedded in that view. My goal is to make my program scroll to a location when it is close to it. 
to do this i added to outlets to my vc. one is the scroll view and the other is the view. The view is just a big rectangle about twice as wide  as the iphones screen and slightly higher. My scroll view scrolls only horizantally, and whenever i lift my finger from scrolling, my goal is if the iphones bounds are within the views bounds. I want the scroll view to manually scroll to the middle of that view. (if you can think of a game menu in angry birds or cut the rope, when the user is scrolling between level packs horizantally, when the user lets go from scrolling it sort of zaps into place to the level the user let go by, this is what i want to mimick).

so, heres my code for both my view and my vc. The only thing i did with storyboards is that i hooked up the two outlets, and set the size of my view.

(the level packs is the vc and the other one is the view).

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "HorizantalLockingView.h"
@interface LevelPacks : UIViewController <ViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet HorizantalLockingView *lockingView;

@end


#import "LevelPacks.h"


@implementation LevelPacks 
@synthesize scrollView=_scrollView;
@synthesize lockingView = _lockingView;



-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGSize size;
    size.width=825;
    size.height=460;
    self.scrollView.contentSize=size;

    self.scrollView.contentOffset=CGPointMake(0, 0);

}




-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.lockingView.delegate=self;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setLockingView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.scrollView=nil;
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}
```

@end

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol ViewDelegate
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@end

@interface HorizantalLockingView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet id <ViewDelegate> delegate;
@end

#import "HorizantalLockingView.h"

@implementation HorizantalLockingView
@synthesize delegate=_delegate;


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGRect location=self.superview.bounds;
 NSLog(@"dkfjdkjf");
    if (CGRectContainsRect(self.frame, location))
    {

        [self.delegate.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(284, 190, 157, 119) animated:YES];
    }




}






@end
```

o, and i did the nslog earlier to see if the method would even do anything, and the nslog never even ran, so obviously somethings wrong.

Im kind of new to this, any help would really be great!

Comment: It seems fine to me (although, a bit sketchy if used in the long run).  Is it possible that `userInteractionEnabled` is not being set properly?  (Also, have you considered just subclassing UIScrollview and saving yourself this delegate nonsense?)

Comment: Have you tried just Enabling paging on the scroll view it does this automatically

Comment: @jammycoder cool ill go that route!

Comment: if you put that as answer i would check it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling paging will automatically do this for you.

```
scrollView.pagingEnabled=YES;
```

Also adding a `UIPageControl` and using the `UIScrollView` delegate methods to update the page control will add a good usability